# Cookie to show video once

Tags: javascript, jquery, setcookie

I have this piece of code. Can anyone help me to set the cookie for 1 day. I need the video to show only once per day.

```
   var rfm = {
    setup: function() {
        jQuery('.video-landing').css('display', 'block');
        jQuery('.logo img').fadeOut(0);
    }

    init: function() {

        if (Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) >= 1040) {

            rfm.setup();

            setTimeout(function() {

                rfm.fadeOutVideo();

                rfm.fadeOutBackground();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    rfm.resizeAndRepositionLogo();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        rfm.fadeOutOverlay();
                        rfm.fadeInSiteLogo();
                    }, 1500)

                }, 0);

            }, 3000);
        }
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    rfm.init();
});
```

Comment: You can use [these functions](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/easily-create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery) to write, read and delete cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery plugin [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to set/read and delete cookies. From the examples:

```
$.cookie('video-disabled', '1', { expires: 1 });
```

The expiration date is provided in days. To read the cookie:

```
$.cookie('video-displayed');
```

Just check if cookie is set. You'll get a value of '1' if cookie exists or 'undefined' in other case.

You may find this page useful - [Mozilla - cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie), however I believe that working with jQuery's plugin is a way easier.